# Many to one relation

Tags: android, android-room

A User can have ONE Car, but a Car can have MULTIPLE Users.

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public Car car;
}

public class Car {
    public int id;
    public String carName;
}
```

How to write entity for something like that?
How to write UserDao to save User and his Car and when I get User I get his Car too?

Answer (score 1):

That time define user id into car and insert car data that time define user id and get user data that time make inner join.

```
public class User {
public int user_id;
public Car car;
}

 public class Car {
public int id;
public int user_id;
public String carName;
 }
```

then make dao like this way.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User u INNER JOIN Car c ON u.user_id =c.user_id")
List<JoinData> getJoinData();
```

and JoinData contact both class data

Comment: i hope you know room db.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Because in your answer a Car can have only one User.

Comment: if you want to insert multple user id then car has multiple user.

Comment: I want to get a User from db with filled field Car.

Comment: as I wrote ONE User can have ONE Car, ONE Car can have MULTIPLE Users.

And I want to get from db User with filled field Car.